# How to stop Docker populating /etc/hosts with all container IPs

Tags: docker

I've started a number of Docker containers (using docker-py) and have noticed that /etc/hosts is populated with the IP and names of all containers, plus various ".bridge" addresses.

Is it possible to prevent this? Ideally I'd only like to have the local host plus linked containers listed (I'm not linking anything to the majority of containers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was removed in [Docker 1.9](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16619).

Comment: Awesome - I shall upgrade and remove my dirty hack.